# Rest API bulk naming convention

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, bulk

Are there any known best practices for web service REST API bulk naming?

Some suggestions for user resource :

```
/api/users-bulk
/api/bulk/users
/api/users/bulk
/api/users/_bulk
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rules, you can use any routes, but I prefer 3rd `/api/users/bulk` in case *bulk* is additional functionality for *users* (like get all users `/api/users`, get user by id `/api/users/:id`, ...). In this case all user related operations are under `/api/user/`.